# Is knowing the second derivative useful in numerical integration?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider Euler's method:

$$
y(t + dt) \approxeq y(t) + \frac{dy}{dt}  dt
$$

which is a simple but not terribly useful way to solve equations when $\frac{dy}{dt}$ is some known function $f(y, t)$ and we know some initial condition $y(t_0) = y_0$.

This method can be improved in two ways:

1. If it so happens that $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$ is also some known function $g(y, t)$, then we can use Taylor series approximation:
   $$
   y(t + dt) \approxeq y(t) + \frac{dy}{dt}dt + \frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}dt^2
   $$
2. Use a better numerical method such as RK4.

My two quesitons are, which of these options will be more accurate, and, is there a way to combine the best of both worlds and incorporate knowledge of the second derivative to improve on the accuracy of RK4?

The practical situation that gives rise to the question was my attempt to simulate orbiting bodies with Newtonian physics, where the second derivative of position (acceleration due to gravity) is a trivial function of position. Using the simple approach with Taylor approximation can write, for position $\vec{r}$, velocity $\vec{v}$, and acceleration $\vec{a}$,
$$
\vec{v}(t_{n+1}) \approxeq \vec{v}(t_n) + \vec{a}(t_n)(t_{n+1} - t)
$$
$$
\vec{r}(t_{n+1}) \approxeq \vec{r}(t_n) + \vec{v}(t_n)(t_{n+1} - t) + \frac{1}{2}\vec{a}(t_n)(t_{n+1} - t)^2
$$

The appearance of the second derivative as a "bonus term" in the second equation makes it tempting to ask if some similar "bonus term" can be applied in the RK4 method or if there are other numerical methods that use the second derivative.

Comment: You could also built a trapezoidal-like formula based on Hermite interpolation. It could be a little more difficult to derive what an explicit version is. One could certainly establish order conditions for using the second derivative. I'm quite certain that this has already been done, but do not have a keyword readily available. For using just the Jacobian of $f$, which gives Rosenbrock methods and exponential methods, this has certainly been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [Generalized Midpoint Rule Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Generalized_midpoint_rule_formula) to approximate the integral even better than "ordinary methods". It asks for infinitely many derivatives, but providing first and second order derivatives $(N=2)$ is already much better than the usual $N=0$ or $N=1$ methods.

Answer (score 0):

Methods such as the one you proposed in 1. are called Taylor methods. You don't need any additional information to compute the second derivative, you can just use the chain rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} f(t,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot f
$$

Your method would then read
$$
y_{n+1} = y_n + h f(t_n,y_n) + \frac{h^2}{2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t_n,y_n) + f(t_n,y_n) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t_n,y_n) \right).
$$

Example: $y'=\sin( xy)$
$$
y'' = (\sin(xy))' = (xy)' \cos (xy) = (y + xy')\cos(xy)=(y+x\sin(xy))\cos(xy)
$$

$$
y_{n+1} = y_n + h \sin(x_n y_n) + \frac{h^2}{2}\left(y_n+x_n \sin(x_n y_n)\right)\cos(x_n y_n)
$$

You can continue this process, obtaining higher order Taylor methods. Suitable approximations of the derivatives in Taylor methods can yield RK methods. For instance, if you consider the approximation

$$
\frac{d}{dt}f(t_n,y_n) \approx \frac{1}{h}(f(t_n+h,y_{n+1})-f(t_n,y_n))\approx \frac{1}{h}(f(t_n+h,y_n+hf(t_n,y_n))-f(t_n,y_n)),
$$

where $y_{n+1}$ is approximated using Euler's method, the second Euler Taylor's method turns into a well known second order RK metyhod.

Comment: In the case of the postion, velocity, acceleration system, I don't think I can compute the partial derivatives needed by the chain rule, because `f` (velocity) is in itself the result of a numerical integration of acceleration. Thinking about it, I guess I lied in the question when I said `f` was a known function. In fact it's only f prime that is known.

Answer (score 0):

One can construct a two-point scheme via the collocation method idea. That is, the solution is approximated on the interval $[t_0,t_1]$ via a polynomial $y(t+sh)=q(s)$ that is demanded to satisfy
\begin{align}
q(0)&=y_0\\
q'(0)&=hf(t_0,y_0),&  q'(1)&=hf(t_1,q(1)),\\
q''(0)&=h^2g(t_0,y_0),& q''(1)&=h^2g(t_1,q(1)).
\end{align}
This is a system of 5 equations that can be used to determine coefficients for a 4th degree polynomial $q$. These coefficients will be functions of $q(1)$ and the values of $f$ and $g$ evaluated there, marking it as implicit method. To get an explicit method of the same order, one would have to generate an $O(h^4)$ approximation of $y_{n+1}$ to insert into the system in the place of $q(1)$ to get back an $O(h^5)$ approximation.

One could for instance use the order 2 Euler-Taylor method to get an $O(h^3)$ approximation, and use the additional first derivative at $t_1$ to compute an $O(h^4)$ approximation with a shorter interpolation formula using a cubic interpolation polynomial.

This collocation idea can be simply extended to include more points in the interval, using one more as example,
\begin{align}
q(0)&=y_0\\
q'(0)&=hf(t_0,y_0),&  q'(0.5)&=hf(t_0+0.5h,q(0.5)),&  q'(1)&=hf(t_1,q(1)),\\
q''(0)&=h^2g(t_0,y_0),& q''(0.5)&=h^2g(t_0+0.5h,q(0.5)),& q''(1)&=h^2g(t_1,q(1)),
\end{align}
the system now has 7 equations, allowing for an degree 6 interpolation polynomial.